# Filtering attribute table in QGIS Atlas?

Tags: qgis, atlas, qgis-print-layouts

I have encountered a problem with filtering "show only features visible within a map" in QGIS Atlas ?composer.

I need to have an attribute table with all mileage posts visible within one map. Although posts on map range from 19+500 to 21+900 km attribute table range from 19+400 to 22+200 km, what is the issue?

I am using QGIS 3.4.5 Madeira?

[image: Attribute table]

Comment: The attribute table is linked to the map called "map 2." Is that the correct map item?

Comment: Yes, this is correct item.